# How do you stop Visual Studio from waiting for the second part of a shortcut-combination?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

If I press a shortcut combination (such as Ctrl+M) – VS waits for the second one. What if I want to cancel it? (e.g. if I mistakenly press the wrong letter and am not sure which one.)

It just waits, with the "(Ctrl+M) was pressed. Waiting for a second key of chord..." in the bottom of the screen.

How do I cancel it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Press Escape. Usually it is not tied as a second keystroke.

Answer (score 3):

I normally press <kbd>Esc</kbd> .

I don't know of any keyboard shortcut where <kbd>Esc</kbd> is the second key press.

Answer (score 2):

There aren't many visual studio Chords that end with Esc so just hit Esc it'll say The key combination is not a command but it prevents you from performing a valid chord.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to record a no-op macro and assign it to Ctrl-M, Esc.  It will say running macro at the bottom quickly and go away.

Comment: Why would this be better than having Ctrl-M, Esc unassigned?

Comment: No better, just won't get the msg at the bottom saying unassigned.

Answer (score 0):

You are in Dvorak Keyboard mode in windows. Press Ctrl+Shift to get out of it...