# Waiting for second key of chord

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have assigned the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to a command.  But when I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, the status bar says <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> was pressed.  Waiting for the second key of the chord...".

If I hit the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, I get "The key combination (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>) is not a command."

How do I activate the command that has been assigned to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>?

I know that this is the same as the question [How do you stop Visual Studio from waiting for the second part of a shortcut-combination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976289/how-do-you-stop-visual-studio-from-waiting-for-the-second-part-of-a-shortcut-com) . But the answer given there (hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>) does not work for me.

Comment: I had the same problem, but I can't understand why it manifested itself "from nothing" without an apparent particular reason. Yesterday wasn't here and today it's here to make me loose time...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Key chords are a keyboard shortcut feature of Visual Studio.  They consist of a sequence of key presses like (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) for *comment code* or (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) for *uncomment code*.

They are activated by the user pressing one <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> combination, then another <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> combo.  For example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on my install of Visual Studio is used for commenting selected text.

In your case, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> is a common chord starter and is used by many chords.  For example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> = **Toggle Word Wrap** and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> = **Workspace Designer.ExpandAll**.

Depending on which developer setting you've chosen for the IDE, Visual Studio might have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> mapped to other chords. In that situation, you cannot use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> by itself for a keyboard shortcut

If this is the case, you can create your own chord, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is not in use on my install of Visual Studio 2012.

**Edit:**
*Also if you remove all key chords that start with (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) then it can work as a non-chord shortcut.*

And your question is not the same as the other question. In that question, the OP has started the chord process (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) and wants to cancel Visual Studio from waiting for the 2nd chord key.

Comment: But I used to use Ctrl+E (alone) in a previous version.

Comment: I would put the "edit", that somewhat invalidates your entire answer, at the beginning

Comment: No solution to the problem was provided though

Comment: this is frustrating. i would expect a "chord" to require simultaneously pressing the keys. in this case, it's more of a "keyboard shortcut" than a chord.

Comment: The opening explanation is valid, and the edit provides the answer to the problem, i.e. remove all conflicting chord bindings, then you can make just Ctrl+E work.

Answer (score 32):

The selected answer is wrong in stating you cannot use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> by itself (at least for Visual Studio 2013).

For those who come from a Mac or other OS background where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> takes you to the end of the current line (the <kbd>End</kbd> key shortcut by default in VS), this is a really frustrating limitation when switching environments.

I found that in Visual Studio 2013 at least, you can remove all the shortcuts that use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> chord (none of which I will ever use) and set the Edit.LineEnd command to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. It just takes a few minutes tracking down the chords to remove (most of them are under the workspace designer).

Comment: FWIW the `End` key will take you to the end of the current line (`Home` for the beginning) all throughout Windows, this is definitely not just a VS shortcut.

Comment: Turns out (VS2015 anyway) you only need remove Ctrl+E, (something) shortcuts that apply to global or editor contexts, after which Ctrl+E will work unchorded in the editor.

Comment: Any hints on how to "track down the chords" that are using a particular combination? I'm trying to map Ctrl-D to "duplicate line" and am having this problem (5 years later, it's still an issue)

Comment: I found it helpful to take a screenshot of all the shortcuts using `Ctrl` + `E` and then place that screenshot to one side of the screen whilst deleting each in turn in Visual Studio. The lengths we go through to set up those little shortcuts :)

Comment: How to "track down the chords":  In the keyboard settings, in the Press Shortcut Keys area, type the keycombo you want.   In the Shortcut currently Used by area, it will list the conflictls.  Search these up, and remove each.

Answer (score 25):

> 1. To see which commands are using your keyboard shortcut at the moment, enter it
>      in the "Press shortcut keys:" edit box. Make sure you don't accidentally click "Assign".
> 2. In the dropdown box "Shortcut currently used by:" you can browse
>      through and manually remove all commands that
>      currently occupy your desired shortcut combination.

[image]

Comment: If you can't find which shortcut is assigned using this control (it's not always easy or possible) and you are using Resharper, Resharper's experimental Shortcuts Live View feature is invaluable in reporting what actual shortcut had been assigned and are currently active (I've only used it in text editor).  If you're using the latest Resharper, press the left Ctrl key three times in text editor to see assignments.

Comment: A lifesaver - thanks! Incidentally, I didn't have to remove all the commands using my shortcut as the first part of a chord, just the ones that used it in Global or Text Editor context. Also, as someone else suggested, a screenshot of all the conflicting chords can make this less tedious.

Answer (score 4):

I came to this question because I had the same problem as the OP, but in the Integrated Terminal of **Visual Studio Code** (not Visual Studio).

My problem:

> I couldn't stop the node server by doing Ctrl+C, because my VS Code was waiting for the "second key of chord"...

I fixed it in the user settings, by unchecking the **Allow Chords** checkbox.

I answered the more suitable question for me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60739908/4345461).

Comment: This fixed my problem. The integrated terminal was unable to backwards search (CTRL+R) because the editor was waiting for a second key of chord. Thank you!

Comment: I think this answer is for "Visual Studio Code", not "Visual Studio", there are no such setting in "Visual Studio".

Comment: @Zitrax , yes, it's for VS Code. Sorry for the confusion. I'll edit my answer to emphasise that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue with my "<" [backquote] key and wasn't able to find the right keybinding in the normal settings. Allow chords wouldn't do anything either.

This is for anyone, who isn't able to reasign the key in the default keybindings:

1. Find the User settings in your terminal.

```
    Windows %APPDATA%\Code\User\

    macOS $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/

    Linux $HOME/.config/Code/User/
```

2. Open the keybindings.json file
3. look for all chords that you would like gone.
4. (Obviously) remove/alter them

I hope I could help some of you!

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it only for the integrated VSCode terminal by adding the following to your setttings.json file:

```
{
    ...
    // Disable chords for terminal usage
    "terminal.integrated.allowChords": false
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools -> Options.
A window will open up, In that Environment -> Keyboard -> Keyboard
And Just Press the Reset button on the right.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSO5U.png)

Answer (score -2):

Do

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>E</kbd>

then

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

More info [here](https://dailydotnettips.com/did-you-know-now-you-can-duplicate-line-of-code-without-loosing-your-clipboard-content-within-visual-studio/):