# Ctrl+C does not stop node server in Command Line from VS Code

Tags: node.js, command-line, visual-studio-code

From a normal Windows command prompt, `ctrl+c` will stop a node server running.

However, if I start the command prompt via the VS Code menu item `Open in Command Prompt`, then pressing `ctrl+c` (even multiple times) does *not* stop the server as usual.

Any idea what is different in the VS Code command prompt compared to the standard windows command prompt?

(Running on Windows 10 x64)
(VS Code 1.11.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this setting solves the problem:

```
"terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\cmd.exe"
```

Sounds like this will be fixed in future versions. (See [Link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25195#issuecomment-297133409) to Github Issue)

Comment: It should be added in "package.json" or "tsconfig.json" ?

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + P, Then type terminal.exter, under Terminal > External: Windows Exec type out this C:\WINDOWS\sysnative\cmd.exe

Comment: Mine was located at C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem as OP, and [RaelB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43645027/4345461) didn't help.

What I did was "disallowed chords" by going to the **User Settings** *(Ctrl + Alt + S on Windows)* **> User Tab (not Workspace tab) > Features > Terminal** and unchecked the **Integrated: Allow Chords** checkbox.

Now I can use my terminal as I would use a regular Windows terminal.

Here's an image of the settings:
[image]

Answer (score 9):

In VS Code you will see a pull-down menu at the top of the terminal in the right corner. If you are in a running node app and want to close it or you are "stuck" the pull-down menu should say node. Click the trashcan (kill terminal) next to the list to close the running node app. You should be returned to the terminal unless you have something else running like another node app. Select bash, powershell, etc from the pull-down menu to navigate back to your command line.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use Code Runner Visual Code Extension use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> (Stop code run)

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> (Run code)

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can simply stop it on "Output" console. Just right-click and select the "Stop code run" option.

[image]