# CMD-K in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I often clear the terminal on macOS with CMD-K (sort of equivalent to `reset`). When I use the terminal in Visual Studio Code and I press CMD-K, the banner at the bottom of the screen shows "(CMD-K) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord..."

How can I make CMD-K pass through the editor to go to the terminal in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60739908/836330 disable the same setting `Terminal: Allow Chords` should work.

Comment: That did not work for me for whatever reason. Seems like VS Code is ignoring the settings value.

Comment: Hmmm, that should work.  Try a reload of vscode?  And you don't have any other terminal-specific keybindings (i.e., with `when: terminalFocus` clauses in them) that do start with Cmd+K + a second chord?

Comment: Suggested solution didn't work. I ended up adding  keybinding to clear `{
        "key": "cmd+K",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.clear",
        "when": "terminalFocus"
    },`

Answer (score 1):

I have occasionally run into this bug (VS Code on MacOS) and each time it randomly would fix itself until recently it kept persisting even through restarting my laptop. I have now found that **closing all open projects** seems to fix this issue for me.

Might be related to how VS Code stores your current workspace state (opened projects and file modifications). It seems maybe these state settings sometimes get corrupted somehow

Answer (score 0):

keybindings.json:

```json
…
    {         
        "key": "cmd+K",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.clear",
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    }
…
```