# How to end running Node server in VS code the (CTRL + C) is not working and every time killing the terminal

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

in VS code the (CTRL + C) is not working and every time have to kill the terminal session.
how can I enabled CTRL + C in Vscode to end server and remain on the same terminal session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the below post discusses about the problem you are facing and ways to overcome it. Could you please have a look at it.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43531894/ctrlc-does-not-stop-node-server-in-command-line-from-vs-code#:~:text=From%20a%20normal%20Windows%20command,stop%20a%20node%20server%20running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43531894/ctrlc-does-not-stop-node-server-in-command-line-from-vs-code#:%7E:text=From%20a%20normal%20Windows%20command,stop%20a%20node%20server%20running).

Regards,
Anbu