# (S) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode and I have some how managed to lock down the 's' key to key chords. Now when ever I press it I'm seeing this is the taskbar but s is not printed. How do I get the s key back again?

[image: exmaple image of s key locked]

Comment: Take a look in your keybindings.json file.

Comment: I did no commands in there have the s key attached to them

Answer (score 2):

The (s) key has probably been set in the keybindings,json. Similar thing happened to me where my (Z) key has been locked to the key chords of "workbench.action.navigateLeft/Right/Up/Down".
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem with (Down Arrow) ,first i tried deleting the content of my settings.json file in VScode but didn't work , then i tried resetting VScode by deleting ~/.config/Code folder; it gave me the welcome page and worked well, but once i signed in with my git account and synced the settings it broke again, then i tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62690821/14958520) with my account signed in and it worked . Hope this helps.