# Disable chordal hotkeys so I can use a custom hotkey

Tags: visual-studio, hotkeys

How can I disable all default shortcuts that use key chords? I am trying to add custom shortcuts, but they do not work because there are dozens of shortcuts that use the keys that I want to use as 'key chords.'

I suppose I could find which ones use my keys and go through one by one to remove them, but that would be extremely tedious, since I can only view the command that use it in the 'used by' dropdown, which only shows a few commands at once. I would have to write each of those down, search for them individually, and then remove all the shortcut assignments associated with them.

The shortcuts I intend to use are "ctrl + R" and "ctrl + T", and map them to VS's 'Comment out selected lines' and 'Uncomment out selected lines' functions.

Comment: Are you intending to map ctrl+R and ctrl+T to a specific Visual Studio command, or something external to Visual Studio?

Comment: I just edited to be more specific. I'm mapping to an Internal Visual Studio command.

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead and assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to Edit.CommentSelection. Under "Use new shortcut in:", select Text Editor. Visual Studio will automatically remove all hotkey key sequences that begin with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> in the Text Editor context.

Comment: That's what I thought, but it didn't. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, Visual Studio says "(Ctrl+R) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord...".

Comment: That behavior is different on my machine. It seems like you're not the only one experiencing this. It seems [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21035286/2908576) has had your problem, though none of the solutions are any good. =~(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (at [VS 2017 (Left Arrow) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52236743/vs-2017-left-arrow-was-pressed-waiting-for-second-key-of-chord/52242794#52242794)) and found Resharper's experimental Shortcuts Live View feature invaluable in reporting what actual shortcut had been assigned and are currently active.  With that you can identify where a chordal kay has been assigned, and remove it. If you're using the latest Resharper, press the left Ctrl key three times in text editor.