# VS 2017 (Left Arrow) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio, when I position my cursor to the right of the semi-colon of the following C#:

`var alpha;`

When I press the left cursor key, nothing happens (call me old-fashioned but I want the cursor to move to the left).  Instead, I notice VS shows in the status bar

(Left Arrow) was pressed.  Waiting for second key of chord...

How can I setup VS so that Left Arrow is not the start of a chord in the editor?

I can go to Keyboard options but how do I find chords that start with Left Arrow?

Comment: Related discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035286/waiting-for-second-key-of-chord does not resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to do this with VS.  However, I found Resharper's Shorts Live View feature (press the left Ctrl key three times in text editor) which displays current shortcuts to be valuable in reporting what actual shortcut had been assigned an are currently active.

It seems I must have pressed Left arrow when assigning a keyboard, so with this tool I could see the name of the command assigned and remove it from Tool | Options.