# How to type Backslash in VScode on Linux

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, backslash, chord

I'm using Visual Studio Code on an Ubuntu 18.04 laptop. I'm loving the editor, but I can't seem to be able to type the backslash (`\`). When I click the backslash I only see the status bar saying:

```
(\) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord...
```

I googled the error above and found [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035286/waiting-for-second-key-of-chord) which talks about the same error when hitting `Ctrl`+`E`.The [highest upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23445912/1650012) says that I need to *"remove all the shortcuts that use the `Ctrl`+`E` chord"*. But I can't find any with just a backslash.

What am I missing here? How can I just type a backslash?

Comment: Check your keyboard shortcuts

Comment: @KaushikAndani - Ok, found it there, thanks. I should've checked that before posting this question.. :-) If you can add your comment as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: I added answer please accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your keyboard shortcuts and change according to your requirements

Thanks